# What do all the parameters in fread and fwrite stand for?

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I started using `fread` and `fwrite` in order to send files over a tcp connection and I was wondering what the parameters for the functions stand for. I've tried reading the documentation, but I didn't understand the difference between the second parameter (size) and the third one (nmemb). Could anyone describe the purpose of every parameter and the difference between the two parameters mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: `nmemb` is a count of items and `size` is a size of a single item. What documentation have you read? Start from `man fread`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk so how should I determine the value for each one when reading and writing from a ```.jpg``` file?

Comment: You decide the size of the single item. You can read a single byte at a time, 2, 3, or 4 bytes etc.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think what I'm trying to get at is what counts as an item? Is there an official definition, or is it something I decide myself?

Comment: It's something you decide yourself.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk what are the uses of items?

Comment: Items are the data you read.

Comment: Why are you using `fread` and `fwrite` for tcp connections instead of `send` and `recv`?

Comment: @StephenNewell I suppose OP wants to `send` data read from a file and/or write to a file data `recv`ed from a socket.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni - That makes sense.  I saw TCP in the question and without code assumed something very odd was going on.

Comment: @StephenNewell is correct

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone describe ... the difference between the two parameters mentioned above?

```
size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);
```

`size` is the size of a single element being read.  E.g. When reading a `double` the size  would be `sizeof(double)` or commonly 8.

`nmemb` is the max number of elements to read.

Importantly, the return value is the number of elements read, not necessarily the number of bytes read.

---

> Could anyone describe purpose of every parameter ... ?

`ptr` is the location in memory to begin saving the data.

`stream` is the `FILE *` pointer to use when reading, often the result of `fopen()`.

---

**Sample Usage**

```
FILE *inf = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
if (inf) {
  double data[N];
  size_t n;
  while ((n = fread(data, sizeof data[0], N, inf)) > 0) {
    printf("Read %zu doubles, first one %g\n", n, data[0]);
  }
  fclose(inf);
}
```

Comment: _When reading a double the size would be ```sizeof(double)``` or commonly 8._ Then how would I determine the size of an element in a ```.jpg``` image? What should I put in both parameters?

Comment: @Serket A .jpg file in a  [complex file structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure).  In various places, code may read different types.    For performance, often the entire file is read as a sea of bytes and then processed.  ALternative read in _segments_ by reading the first few bytes to determine how to read the rest of the segment.

Comment: Then how should I do that? Whenever I put in 1 as the number of elements and  as the number of bytes per element, it returns a Seg Fault

Comment: @Serket Certainly your code description is not enough to solve that problem.  Recommend to review your findings here and later post your .jpg read code as another question.  An common candidate problem is that your receive buffer is too small.

Answer (score 1):

`fread` and `fwrite`, defined in `<stdio.h>` (docs [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)) have the following signature:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *" stream );
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

1. Both of them require a pointer to a buffer, `ptr`, which would contain the starting address where data has to be copied (`fread`) or where to copy from (`fwrite`)
2. Both of them are supposed to copy `nmemb` elements each of `size` bytes. S For example, if you are copying a buffer of 100 characters

   fread( ptr, 1, 100, filePointer );

because the size of a `char` is 1. In the general case in which you are copying N elements of type `myType`

```
 fread( ptr, sizeof(myType), N, filePointer );
```

and in this case totally `sizeof(myType) * N` bytes will be read.

3. They require a valid pointer to file (`FILE *`) obtained with a *successfull* call to the `fopen` function (described [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)).
4. Talking about their return value, a can't write a better descriptions than the one contained in the linked documentation:

> On success, `fread()` and `fwrite()` return the number of **items** read or written. This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1. If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

So, on success, it will return at most `nmemb`.